# How to add native DLLs of SQL Server CE 4 private install from nuget package to ClickOnce publication?

Tags: .net, dll, sql-server-ce, nuget, clickonce

In VS2013 I have created a small sample application that uses the nuget package

- `EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact`

Besides the Entity Framework this package adds the native DLLs of SQL Server Compact 4.0 for private deployment somewhere under the hidden "packages" folder of the VS-project.

When I compile the project these native DLLs are magically copied to bin\Debug into x86 and amd64 folders. The application finds them there and runs just fine.

However, when I want to publish my project as ClickOnce there is a problem:

- The native DLLs do not show up under Publish -> Application Files
- Normally files can be added to Application Files by setting the Build Action to "Content". But as all folders&files under the "packages" folder are greyed out (not part of project) these files don't even have the property Build Action.

Including the DLLs a second time in a regular project folder would probably work but I guess that's not the idea of nuget...

What's the proper way of including native DLLs from a nuget package into a ClickOnce publication?

Comment: Your best approach would be to include add native dll files (including *all* files in the x86 amd amd64 folders) as content files with your app

Comment: Erik, thanks. Simple second copy of the x86 folder with BuildAction=Content worked as expected. 
Btw.: Thanks for your very helpful SQLCE blog and the SQLCE Tools!!!

Comment: You are welcome Andreas, glad you find it useful. Would be grateful for a candid review at VS Gallery!